# adding gps google map in my app in unity3d

Tags: google-maps, unity-game-engine, gps

I want to add a feature to the application on unity3d to locate  the user of my application.

Is there a way to do this (with the knowledge that I work on unity3d beginner)?

Thank you for all

Answer (score 2):

You can use the unity3d **LocationServices**.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    IEnumerator Start() {
        if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
            return;

        Input.location.Start();
        int maxWait = 20;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            maxWait--;
        }
        if (maxWait < 1) {
            print("Timed out");
            return; 
        }
        if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed) {
            print("Unable to determine device location");
            return;
        } else
            print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " +
            Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + 
            Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " +
            Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + 
            Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
            Input.location.Stop();
        }
}
```